# Unable to load remote video track in VideoRenderer, When onAddStream() invoked

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

I'm implementing webrtc in android. I could not load the remote video stream after setting the remoteDescription in peerConnection object.
I'm getting the remote audio,video track , When onAddStream() involked(org.webrtc.VideoTrack@37471a54). But could not load that in Videorenderer.

```
@Override
        public void onAddStream(final MediaStream stream) {
            Log.d("checklog","onaddstream"+stream.audioTracks.get(0)+stream.videoTracks.get(0));
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (peerConnection == null ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (stream.audioTracks.size() > 1 || stream.videoTracks.size() > 1) {
                        Log.d("onAddstreamerror","Weird-looking stream: " + stream);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (stream.videoTracks.size() == 1) {
                        remoteVideoTrack = stream.videoTracks.get(0);
                        remoteVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
                        remoteVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(remoteRender));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is the video just not displayed? Does your local stream render ok?

Comment: Local stream is rendering perfectly.remote video just not displayed. But i'm getting the video track onAddStream()(org.webrtc.VideoTrack@37471a54).

Comment: I fixed the problem. I didn't set the ice candidate properly in peerconnection object. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Actually I missed the below part in my code
`public void setRemoteIceCandidate() {      for (IceCandidate ice : remoteIceCandidate) {         peerConnection.addIceCandidate(ice);     }     remoteIceCandidate = new ArrayList<IceCandidate>(); }
`
After adding the ice candidate  it is working fine now.

Comment: I don't get it! Are you receiving the IceCandidates through signalling or embedded in remote SDP? If it is embedded in remote SDP then you don't need to set the IceCandidates separately.

Comment: Also check if you are using `PeerConnection.ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_CONTINUALLY` in your `PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration`. When I used `GATHER_ONCE` instead, my code actually worked, but ICE took very long time. I saw first frame of remote VideoTrack only after four minutes or so.

Comment: the problem is not about candidate, it's base on sdp return from server when subcrisber attach to room, " m=audio.." -> no videoTrack