# Remote video doesn't load when onAddStream() is called

Tags: android, webrtc, kurento

I am implementing a `webRTC` android application, and the servers that i am communicating with are a signaling server(via websockets) and a kurento media server.

Time sequence is:

- clients subscribe to the server
- every client sent `sdpOffer`
- every client sent  all the `iceCandidate` that will be created
- signaling server send the `iceCandidate` to every client
- signaling server send to the clients the `sdpAnswers`  which originate from kurento media server

My mobile clients subscribe to the server and they send theirs `sdpOffers`.
After `ice trickle` the signaling server sending back the `sdpAnswers` from kurento media server.

So, i am getting the `startCommunication` messages and the remote description is set successfully with the `sdpAnswers` from kurento media server.
I have check all my sdp and ice packages, they are all as expected, and all `webRTC` related callbacks are successful.

After setting the `remoteDescription` in `peerConnection`,

the `onAddStream()` is invoked and i am getting the `videoTrack`.But the video is not rendering..

my onAddStream:

```
 override fun onAddStream(p0: MediaStream?) {

            super.onAddStream(p0)
            p0?.videoTracks?.get(0)?.addSink(remote_view)

            Log.d(TAG, "on add stream" + p0?.videoTracks?.size )
            Log.d(TAG,App.rtcClient.peerConnection?.iceConnectionState().toString())
            Log.d(TAG,App.rtcClient.peerConnection?.iceGatheringState().toString())
        }
```

init of the remote view:

```
   fun initSurfaceView(view: SurfaceViewRenderer) = view.run {
      setMirror(true)
      setEnableHardwareScaler(true)
      init(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, null)
   }

  ....

  App.rtcClient.initSurfaceView(remote_view)
```

xml of the remote view:

```
 <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
    android:id="@+id/remote_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/local_view" />
```

*I am not getting any errors and my local stream is rendering perfectly.*

So, i am debugging the app without knowing where to go next, because is not clear where this problem comes from.

This exact question exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963986/unable-to-load-remote-video-track-in-videorenderer-when-onaddstream-invoked) but there is no answers and it is 5 y.o

if you need any additional info please comment.

Update: **Exact** the same behavior exists in the iOS version too - no video rendering.

Comment: Check if you are actually getting video frames. Easiest way -- write a simple implementation of `VideoSink` that just logs the received frames and add it to track with `.addSink()`

Comment: @lyrjie I am not getting. With the same implementation - I tried a p2p connection without the kurento server and am getting the video frames. Via the kurento just a blank screen - but the onAddStream callback is called